# Can I add new class inside the same element using jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What I mean, is there a way to write sth like this?

```
<input
        className="form-control"
        onChange={() => { 
          this.classList.add('is-valid');  //where this is input element
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Do you want to add a className on the input field when you change it?

Comment: You shouldn't manually mutate the DOM when using React. What if the component rerenders (and the added class name is lost)? You can use state to determine which class names should and shouldn't exist.

Comment: Did you tried something like like `className={`form-control ${new_class}`}`

Comment: @VilfredDreijer yes

Comment: Then the answer from T J would work. Though I would change `const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false)` with a state hook holding a value (`const [value, setValue] = useState()`), since it's likely you need that for the `<input /> ` anyway.  
Then in the `<input />` you want to add `onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a local state ([`useState`)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and conditional expression as shown below:

```
function App() {

  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

  return (<input
    className={'form-control' + (isValid ? ' is-valid' : '')}
    onChange={() => {
      setIsValid(true);
    }}
  />)
}
```